# Получение значений всех отмеченных checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма с чекбоксами.

```
var sitevalue = $('#siteform input:checkbox:checked').val();
alert(sitevalue);
```

этот код выводит только значение первого отмеченного бокса (один алерт выскакивает), хотя отмечено несколько. Как получить значение всех отмеченных чекбоксов? Чтобы было столько алертов, сколько отмечено чекбоксов

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 $('#siteform input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Всегда думал, что `$('#siteform input[type="checkbox"]:checked')` `o_O` Почему так?

Comment: это эквивалентные записи подробности [тут](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/).

Comment: @FLK благодарю

@vinnie после смены URL выполнение javascript обрывается. Создайте новый вопрос, может придумаем что-нибудь

Comment: @vinnie в любом случае это тема нового вопроса. в коменты много кода не напишешь.

Comment: @vinnie, да, я уже знаю ответ.